# Find unique value of string array and keep order

Tags: java

I have a `String[]` with values like so:

```java
line_str = "1,3,4,3,11,2,2,6,7"
```

I want to find unique value and keep the arrangement of value

```java
unique_str="1,3,4,11,2,6,7"
```

I'm using a `HashSet` but the output is:

```
[1,6,7,4,11,3,2]
```

Here is my code:

```java
String line_str = "1,3,4,3,11,2,2,6,7";
String[] str_arr = line_str.split(",");
Set<String> uniqueValue = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(str_arr));
Toast.makeText(this, uniqueValue.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Is there an implementation of Set that maintains insertion order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A HashSet will ensure no duplications and a LinkedHashSet will ensure each element remains in its designated position;

```
String line_str = "1,3,4,3,11,2,2,6,7";
String[] str_arr = line_str.split(",");
Set<Integer> uniqueNumbers = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
for(String num : str_arr) {
    uniqueNumbers.add(Integer.parseInt(num));
}
```

If your input has any variance then you will need to handle that.

Comment: You don't really need to convert to Integer, the set will contain unique values anyway and the end result is supposed to be a string so that would mean another conversion

Comment: i use ->Set<String> uniqueValue = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(str_arr));

Answer (score 0):

Using streams :

```
     String line_str = "1,3,4,3,11,2,2,6,7";
     String unique_str = Pattern.compile(",")
                                .splitAsStream(line_str)
                                .distinct()
                                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
     System.out.println(unique_str);
```